# How can I make apache run cgi files in all directories under ./www ?

Tags: python, apache2

My friend and I are working on an art site and one of our scripts works fine in most of the upper levels of ./www but once we get down to ./www/testing/project2/cgi-bin/.. cgi files seem to only return 500 errors. The exact same scripts work higher up the directory.
Any way to coax apache into letting us run this cgi file in these lower directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default apache2 configuration in Ubuntu will enable the ExecCGI option only for a specific directory below your main one (cgi-bin).  You can however add this option to any directory you like including your main one.

Find the Apache configuration for that site.  Look for the relevant `<Directory>` section which will either be in one of your virtual host config files, or if it's site-wide, it'll be in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.  You can either edit it here, or put your new configuration into a separate file under `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`.

You'll need to add `ExecCGI` to your `Options` directive (or create a new `Options` parameter with `+ExecCGI` added).

Example for editing an existing Options directive:

```
<Directory /usr/home/joe/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Example for creating a new Options directive for a directory that overrides the Apache-wide default one:

```
<Directory /usr/home/joe/www>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```